# Is it possible to have a capture within an interpolated regex?

Tags: regex, raku, string-interpolation

I wanted to generate regex from an existing list of values, but when I attempted to use a capture within it, the capture was not present in the match. Is it not possible to have a capture using interpolation, or am I doing something wrong?

```
my @keys = <foo bar baz>;
my $test-pattern = @keys.map({ "<$_>" }).join(' || ');

grammar Demo1 {
  token TOP {
    [
      || <foo>
      || <bar>
      || <baz>
    ] ** 1..* % \s+
  }

  token foo { 1 }
  token bar { 2 }
  token baz { 3 }
}

grammar Demo2 {
  token TOP {
    [ <$test-pattern> ] ** 1..* % \s+
  }

  token foo { 1 }
  token bar { 2 }
  token baz { 3 }
}

say $test-pattern, "\n" x 2, Demo1.parse('1 2 3'), "\n" x 2, Demo2.parse('1 2 3');
```

```
<foo> || <bar> || <baz>

｢1 2 3｣
 foo => ｢1｣
 bar => ｢2｣
 baz => ｢3｣

｢1 2 3｣
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule for determining whether an atom of the form `<...>` captures without further ado is whether or not it starts with a letter or underscore.

If an assertion starts with a letter or underscore, then an identifier is expected/parsed and a match is captured using that identifier as the key in the enclosing match object. For example, `<foo::baz-bar qux>` begins with a letter and captures under the key `foo::baz-bar`.

If an assertion does *not* begin with a letter or underscore, then by default it does not capture.

---

To capture the results of an assertion whose first character is *not* a letter or underscore you can either put it in parens or name it:

```
( <$test-pattern> ) ** 1..* % \s+
```

or, to name the assertion:

```
<test-pattern=$test-pattern> ** 1..* % \s+
```

or (just another way to have the same naming effect):

```
$<test-pattern>=<$test-pattern> ** 1..* % \s+
```

---

If all you do is put an otherwise non-capturing assertion in parens, then you have *not* switched capturing on for that assertion. Instead, you've merely *wrapped it in an outer capture*. The assertion remains non-capturing, and *any sub-capture data of the non-capturing assertion is thrown away*.

Thus the output of the first solution shown above (wrapping the `<$test-pattern>` assertion in parens) is:

```
｢1 2 3｣
 0 => ｢1｣
 0 => ｢2｣
 0 => ｢3｣
```

Sometimes that's what you'll want to simplify the parse tree and/or save memory.

In contrast, if you *name* an otherwise non-capturing assertion with either of the named forms shown above, then by doing so you convert it into a capturing assertion, which means any *sub* capture detail will be retained. Thus the *named* solutions produce:

```
｢1 2 3｣
 test-pattern => ｢1｣
  foo => ｢1｣
 test-pattern => ｢2｣
  bar => ｢2｣
 test-pattern => ｢3｣
  baz => ｢3｣
```

Comment: That second one has a rather interesting outcome, it ends up containing the captures I wanted within that new capture!

`
｢1 2 3｣
 test-pattern => ｢1｣
  foo => ｢1｣
 test-pattern => ｢2｣
  bar => ｢2｣
 test-pattern => ｢3｣
  baz => ｢3｣
`

Comment: @DanielMita I've responded to your comment and am fairly confident I have now correctly and fully described the situation.

Comment: Aha, I didn't follow at first but now I get it! I was expecting direct interpolation with <$var>, but it hadn't occurred to me that the effects of the surrounding <...> were applicable.

Comment: If variable containing a *string* is interpolated as `$test-pattern`, not `<$test-pattern>`, then it's inserted *as a string* -- `<foo>` is inserted as 5 character string, *not* as an assertion `<foo>`. If a variable containing a *regex* is interpolated that way then it works as a regex -- but is also not captured. So `my $test-pattern = / <{ @keys.map({ "<$_>" }).join(' || ') }> /;` and then `token TOP { $test-pattern ** 1..* % \s+` works, but without `<foo>` etc captures. With `<$test-pattern>`, variable can be string *or* regex and it'll work -- but still won't capture `<foo>` etc details.